# JAAS, doing login from outside the container

Tags: java, jaas

I have an application with JAAS and i need do an external login from the legacy, so i wrote a servlet with this code bellow, it works fine, but when i do another submit the JAAS tries authenticate again and has failure, and the user is redirected to login page.

here is doPost method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    NfWebCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new NfWebCallbackHandler(req);

    LoginContext loginContext = null;

    boolean loginSuccess = true;

    try {
        loginContext = new LoginContext("MyLoginContext", callbackHandler);
        loginContext.login();
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        loginSuccess = false;
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req
                .getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsf");
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    if (loginSuccess) {

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(req
                .getParameter("targetUrl"));
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }

}
```

any idea is welcome! thanks!

Comment: I don't understand which one is your problem. Is it a problem that the Login module is called twice for the same session? Or, is it that you don't know why the Login module is failing on the second attempt?

Comment: Hi Reynolds,

Well, i dont care if it will call the loginModule twice , i dont know why is failing after the success in the first attempt, it seems the "subject" is not being recognized by the container.

Thank you for the reply!

Comment: AFAIK, the subject will be recognized only if the container manages the entire process; most containers store the subject in the session (in a field not modifiable by the developer), but only if you configure the appropriate auth scheme. In short, you'll need to specify FORM-based authentication to send the auth request to j_security_check.

Comment: yes that's my point... i have this FORM-based authentication working fine, and i have this servlet for outside acess. In the snippet above i did the same process of a login form-based , apparently... even when i look at my LoginModule implementation, the same things are made...

Comment: Hmm, then your specific failure on the second attempt might be that the Login Module expects the first session/user to be logged out, before the user is allowed to login again.

Comment: actually the second try never happens, the user is redirected to login page immediatly before the submit, JAAS intercepts the request as a unauthorized user's request...

Comment: Ok, then my answer below holds. Since your code is performing the task of authenticating the user, it must remember the subject, and use it across HTTP requests, and propagate it downstream if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to register my solution for this case, i used this class:

org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.login.WebAuthentication

i wrote something like that:

```
        WebAuthentication webAuthentication = new WebAuthentication();
        req.getSession().setAttribute("webAuthentication", webAuthentication);
```

I dont remember where i found this, but was very useful!

Thanx Vineet Reynolds, the only one who tried to help me hehehe

Answer (score 2):

When you use a JAAS Login Module outside the purview of the container (or at least in a mannaer unrecognizable to the container), the container will not be aware of the fact that the Subject and the set of Principals (associated with the subject) are to be stored and managed by the container.

When you use one of the container-managed authentication schemes, the container actually stores the subject in the Session implementation class (at least in Tomcat 6, this is true), in a manner that is completely opaque to the developer; using `getAttribute()` on the session object will never return the Subject, and neither can use `setAttribute()` to override the Subject. When needed, the subject is retrieved from this session field and used for various purposes by the container; for instance, when you invoke `getUserPrincipal()` or `getRemoteUser()` on the `HttpServletRequest` object, the Principal associated with the Subject is actually used to return the result.

If you need to get the container to do all this heavy-lifting for you, then you need to use the JAAS Login module in conjunction with a container managed authentication scheme. If you do not want to go this way, then you'll need to "remember" the Subject and the Principals for the duration of the session; not to forget, all of this has to be done in a secure manner.

Comment: Thanx Reynolds, i've found everthing i need at this link: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/WebAuthentication, see ya!